# Problem with std::vector and a custom class that includes sf:: Text, C++, SFML

Tags: c++, vector, sfml, stdvector

I am creating a graphical application using the SFML library. I have a class, `Square`, that creates a square block with a letter inside. This class has members `sf:: Font` and `sf::Text` except for the square itself (`sf::RectangleShape`). The constructor of this class takes the size of the side of the square, its position, the path to the font that is located in the project folder, and the letter that will be written to `sf:: Text`. The class also contains the `draw()` method, which takes an object of the `sf::RenderWindow` type and draws the square itself and the text using it.

*Here's the problem*. When I create multiple instances of a square (and therefore a letter with it) using separate variables, everything works fine, but when I try to push_back the squares in `std::vector`, everything breaks, errors fly out in Debug mode, and in Release mode only small dots are drawn instead of letters and the program does not work correctly, the window may stop responding
(Just squares *without letters* work fine with `std::vector` and they are drawn normally)

I think that there are errors related to dynamic memory, pointers or iterators, but I myself can not figure out and understand what is happening, thank you in advance for your help.

The code for better understanding:

```
class Square
{
public:
    RectangleShape m_square;
    Font m_font;
    Text m_text;

    Square(int size, Vector2f pos, string fontPath, string letter)
    {
        m_square.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 50));
        m_square.setSize(Vector2f(size, size));
        m_square.setPosition(pos);
    
        if (!m_font.loadFromFile(fontPath))
            wcout << "Error loading the font!" << endl;

        m_text.setFont(m_font);
        m_text.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 220));
        m_text.setCharacterSize(size * 0.8);
        m_text.setString(letter);
        m_text.setPosition(Vector2f((pos.x - m_text.getGlobalBounds().left) + (size - m_text.getGlobalBounds().width) / 2, pos.y));
    }   

    void draw(RenderWindow& window)
    {
        window.draw(m_square);
        window.draw(m_text);
    }

};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "Square.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 10;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1200, 800), "My window", Style::Default, settings);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    Square sq1(50, Vector2f(100, 100), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "A");
    Square sq2(50, Vector2f(200, 100), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "B");
    Square sq3(50, Vector2f(100, 200), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "C");
    Square sq4(50, Vector2f(200, 200), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "D");

    vector<Square> squares;
    squares.push_back(Square(50, Vector2f(400, 100), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "A"));
    squares.push_back(Square(50, Vector2f(500, 100), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "B"));
    squares.push_back(Square(50, Vector2f(400, 200), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "C"));
    squares.push_back(Square(50, Vector2f(500, 200), "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "D"));

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear(Color::White);

        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        sq1.draw(window);
        sq2.draw(window);
        sq3.draw(window);
        sq4.draw(window);

        for (auto& s : squares)
        {
            s.draw(window);
        }

        window.display();

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the program
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPtNZ.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start reading documentation before coding.. [Text::setFont](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81) *The font argument refers to a font that must exist as long as the text uses it. Indeed, the text doesn't store its own copy of the font, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function. If the font is destroyed and the text tries to use it, the behavior is undefined.* you have dangling reference to font due to shallow copy of it - performed by default copy operation of `Square`.

Comment: Use smart pointers to keep all your object - to avoid shallow copy of them, or provide proper operations like copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

Answer (score 0):

As both a simple workaround and a small memory & performance improvement, consider storing your fonts in a `std::map<std::string, sf::Font>` instead.
This data structure allows you to map the font name to the object, and it has the nice property that objects in it don't move around as you add new ones.

```
// add this at top level
std::map<std::string, sf::Font> fonts;

// Change the Square constructor as such:
Square(int size, Vector2f pos, string fontPath, string letter) {
  if (auto it = fonts.find(fontPath); it == fonts.cend()) {
    // Font was not created before.
    auto& font = fonts[fontPath]; // this access will create a Font object and automatically store it in the map
    if (!font.loadFromFile(fontPath))
      wcout << "Error loading the font!" << endl;
  }
  ...
  m_text.setFont(fonts[fontPath]);
  ...
}
```

and of course get rid of the `m_font` member.